# RUVadj Bioconductor package - Error in if (temp[[4]] > 0) df = df + temp[[4]] else df = Inf - what does the error mean and how do I fix it?

Tags: r, bioconductor

So im trying to run a RUVadj using the missmethyl package so that I can perform a GO analysis but I'm getting an error and kinda stuck on it for a while now.

Any helps appreciated.

```
setwd('C:/Users/saeed/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/minfi/')
baseDir <- system.file("extdata/", package = "minfi")
list.files(baseDir)
list.files(file.path(baseDir))

targets <- read.metharray.sheet(baseDir, "Book3.csv")
targets

sub(baseDir, "", targets$Basename)

#create RGchannel set

RGset <- read.metharray.exp(targets = targets)
RGset

#convert RGchannel set to Methyl Set

Illumina.Mset <- preprocessIllumina(RGset)
meth <- getMeth(Illumina.Mset)
unmeth <- getUnmeth(Illumina.Mset)
M <- log2((meth + 100)/(unmeth + 100))
# setup the factor of interest
```

> head(M)

| Probes | R01C01 | R02C01 | R03C01 | R04C01 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cg18478105 | -5.3623835 | -5.7746928 | -5.9516744 | -6.1046525 |
| cg09835024 | -0.6944983 | -0.5598865 | -0.4569663 | -0.5867908 |
| cg14361672 | 1.1299404 | 1.3785078 | 1.7588722 | 2.5595258 |
| cg01763666 | 3.5058198 | 3.4902609 | 4.1672918 | 4.4789099 |
| cg12950382 | 3.4256322 | 3.4222108 | 4.5712464 | 3.1377309 |
| cg02115394 | -3.3834974 | -3.5854853 | -3.9439757 | -4.0201787 |

```
grp1 <- factor(targets$Status, labels=c(0,1))
```

> grp1
> [1] 0 1 0 1,
> Levels: 0, 1

```
#####RUVm Stage 1 analysis####

design_mat <- model.matrix(~treatment, data=metadata.GS8)

lfit1 <- lmFit(M, design_mat)
lfit2 <- eBayes(lfit1) 

topTable(lfit2)
```

topTable(lfit2)

Removing intercept from test coefficients
Probes |    logFC |   AveExpr  |        t |     P.Value |adj.P.Val  |       B |
|---------|----------|------------|----------|-------------|-----------|---------|
cg21013536 |-7.639218| -3.4556441 |-25.927283| 5.861993e-07| 0.5077881 |-4.298458|
cg13786191 | 3.522940| -1.7614698 | 12.805259| 2.666645e-05| 1.0000000 |-4.307538|
cg08624472 |-3.823590| -5.8593786 |-12.355875| 3.226576e-05| 1.0000000 |-4.308402|
cg03266200 |-3.013029| -0.6756144 |-11.830490| 4.066147e-05| 1.0000000 |-4.309534|
cg13438944 |-4.249454|  0.1332814 | -9.873210| 1.056582e-04| 1.0000000 |-4.315336|
cg26023019 |-6.058192| -2.6566187 | -9.424544| 1.347486e-04| 1.0000000 |-4.317158|
cg16628641 |-2.995192| -2.9981631 |-8.630200 | 2.128654e-04| 1.0000000 |-4.321040|
cg17731560 |-2.738988|  1.3694938 | -8.207441| 2.757265e-04| 1.0000000 |-4.323532|
cg25146017 |-2.728432| -5.4878603 | -8.116016| 2.920405e-04| 1.0000000 |-4.324117|
cg00759619 | 1.913320| -3.2645310 |  8.005232| 3.133449e-04| 1.0000000 |-4.324850|

```
topl1 <- topTable(lfit2, num=Inf)

ctl3 <- rownames(M) %in% rownames(topl1[topl1$P.Value > 0.5,])
```

> table(ctl3)
> ctl3

| FALSE | TRUE |
| --- | --- |
| 308889 | 557349 |

```
rfit <- RUVfit(Y = M, X = grp1, ctl = ctl3, randomization=TRUE) #degrees of freedom less than 4 hence the package suggests proceeding with randomization = TRUE

rfit1 <- RUVAdj(M, rfit)
```

rfit1 <- RUVadj(M, rfit)
Error in if (temp[[4]] > 0) df = df + temp[[4]] else df = Inf :
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

**This is the error**

it says missing values where true/false needed, and I'm not sure what to do about this.
Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Hey Saeed, same issue here. Have you ever figured it out?